# Update Profile Attributes via Journey Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

Goal: Update the subscriber profile attribute at time of send using Journey Builder and Salesforce Data Event.

We are using subscriber filters to restrict visibility to the All Subscribers list for certain BUs. Part of that solution requires that we set the Profile Attributes with a specific value as a criteria for this filter.

I was told that there is a way to set Profile Attributes for a subscriber during a send if the column in the data extension matches exactly with the Profile Attribute that has been configured. Our journeys are setup with a Salesforce data event entry which means the system will create a corresponding DE for the journey and the field name will correspond to the field in Sales Cloud (field name = [Contact.BUName__c] instead of the profile named [BUName]). When I try to perform a send, the Profile attribute does not get updated. I also tried to create a column that is named BUName and have the same error.

Are we going about this the right way ?

Comment: Do you need to update in realtime, or would an hourly Automation uploading from your Journey Entry Data Extension into All Subscribers suite your use case?

Comment: @Macca, it should be real time as we do not leave any time for someone from another child BU to see the subscriber.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think journey builder or email send will update the profile attributes during sends. Irrespective of the attribute name match.
The payload to update the all subscriber has to be serialised. If my assertion is true, it uses establish contact api not patch update contact.

Recommendation is to perform import activity to all subscriber